# How to write test cases for Dynamic picklist

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

I have a dynamic picklist that I am displaying on the visualforce page.

Here is my visualforce code:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!SelectedNomination}" size="1" id="a">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!contactlist}"></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
```

Here is my apex code:

```
public Id SelectedNomination { get; set;}
public List<Nominator__c> Nominators = new List<Nominator__c>();

// The below code is in my class constructor method.

public List<SelectOption> contactlist
{

    get
    {

        String state = application.Congressional_State_Territory__c.substring(0,2);

        Nominators = [Select Id, Name, Class_Year__c, Contact_Name__c, 
              Nominator_Code__c, Nominator_Type__c from Nominator__c WHERE 
              FirstTwoLetters__c =: state and Nominator_Type__c= 
              'Congressional - House' and Class_Year__c =: 
              application.Class_Year__c and Status__c =:'Active' ];

        contactlist = new List<SelectOption>();

        for(Nominator__c nom : Nominators)
        {
            contactlist.add(new SelectOption(nom.Id, nom.Name + ' ' + 
            nom.Contact_Name__c));
        }

        return contactlist;
    }
    set {}
}
```

I am saving the user chosen value in SelectedNomination variable and I am saving the value in congressional district field in the saveandcontinue fucntion

```
public pagereference saveAndContinue() {

    application.Congressional_District__c = SelectedNomination;     
    update application;

    Pagereference Page = new Pagereference('/apex/usafa_PCQ_Page_4');
    Page.setRedirect(true);
    return Page;
```

}

Test class:

I have started writing the code but it's in pieces and I am stuck.

```
Nominator__c Nominators = [Select Id, Name, Class_Year__c, Contact_Name__c, Nominator_Code__c, Nominator_Type__c from Nominator__c 
WHERE FirstTwoLetters__c =: 'GA' and Nominator_Type__c= 'Congressional - House' and Class_Year__c =: '2023' and Status__c =:'Active' ];

contactlist = new List<SelectOption>();

for(Nominator__c nom : Nominators)

{
    contactlist.add(new SelectOption(nom.Id, nom.Name + ' ' + 
    nom.Contact_Name__c));
}

//u is my current user

 system.runAs(u){

      usafa_PCQPage3Controller controllerClass = new usafa_PCQPage3Controller();

      List<SelectOption> selOpts=controllerClass.contactlist;

}
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think this line `set {}` maybe cause you some grief, a custom setter needs to at least look like `set { contactlist = value; }` or it won't actually set the value. A default setter just looks like `set;` without the {}.

Answer (score 2):

Build your `Nominator__c` object with all the requirements that your query requires in the `get;set;`.  You don't need to do that query in your Test class or build at that `contactList`.

```
List<Nominator__c> nomList = new List<Nominator__c>();

Nominator__c n = new Nominator__c();
n.Name = 'A Name';
//Plus whatever you need for your WHERE clauses
nomList.add(n);
n = new Nominator__c();
n.Name = 'B Name';
//Plus whatever you need for your WHERE clauses
nomList.add(n);
insert nomList;
```

Call your build method

```
usafa_PCQPage3Controller controllerClass = new usafa_PCQPage3Controller();
List<SelectOption> options = controllerClass.contactlist;

System.assertEquals(options.size(), 2);
```

You should also assert that you have the correct names in the picklist.. Just remember the only thing you need to test here is the actual method. nothing before, nothing after.  Just the creation of the select options

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried the above solution. It gives me error on this line
List<SelectOption> options = controllerClass.contactlist();

Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void contactlist()

Comment: @Student I added a line, `usafa_PCQPage3Controller controllerClass = new usafa_PCQPage3Controller();`

Comment: Yes I have added that line too still getting the error.

Comment: I don't know then, your posted code is leaving out some context..

Comment: `contactList` isn't a function, you don't need the `()`, you should be able to access it via `List<SelectOption> options = controllerClass.contactlist;`

Comment: @battery.cord I tried without (). It successfully saved but when I run the tests it fails and gives me the following error on this line    List<SelectOption> options=controllerClass.contactlist;
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: Did you ever change that setter? If not, if might not be able to save any values to the variable. Otherwise, its the same debugging as any null pointer exception, just keep trying to figure out exactly what is null, and then make sure its set in your test.